# Reason for receiving KeyError: '[...] not in index' while using tensorflow.compat.v1 to train and build a standard DNN model?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm really new to building machine learning algorithms, so I'm going to try giving as much information as I can because I'm not sure what could be causing this to happen.

I've been playing around with the code, trying different optimizers etc. However, since I can't seem to figure out why the error is occurring, most of my attempts are just best guesses.

[Here's my data on GitHub](https://github.com/MrChadMWood/Misc/blob/main/processed_df.csv)

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

processed_df = pd.read_csv('data/clean_hotel_reviews.csv') # Sentiment: 0=happy; 1=not happy

# Splits data for supervised model
train, validate, test = np.split(processed_df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42), # Shuffles data
                                 [int(.7*len(processed_df)), int(.85*len(processed_df))]) # Splits 0-70%; 70-85%; 85-100%
```

```
# Training input
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': train['description']}, 
    train.sentiment,
    batch_size=256, 
    num_epochs=None, 
    shuffle=True)

# Prediction for training set
predict_train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': train['description']}, 
    train.sentiment, 
    shuffle=False)

# Prediction for validation set
predict_val_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': validate['description']}, 
    validate.sentiment, 
    shuffle=False)

# Prediction for test set
predict_test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': test['description']}, 
    test.sentiment, 
    shuffle=False)
```

```
# Instantiates sentence embeding feature
embedding_feature = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key='review',
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2", # Leverages Universal Sentence Encoder
    trainable=False)

# Standard DeepNN with two hidden layers
dnn = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[512, 128],
    feature_columns=[embedding_feature],
    n_classes=2,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    dropout=0.1,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.005))
```

```
import time

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

# Reduced from book example for easier computation
TOTAL_STEPS = 100
STEP_SIZE = 10

for step in range(0, TOTAL_STEPS+1, STEP_SIZE):
    print()
    print('-'*50)
    print('Training for step: ', step)
    
    start_time = time.time()
    dnn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=STEP_SIZE)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    
    print('Seconds Elapsed:', elapsed_time)
    print('Eval (Train):', dnn.evaluate(input_fn=predict_train_input_fn))
    print('Eval (Validation):', dnn.evaluate(input_fn=predict_val_input_fn))
```

Here's the traceback:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Training for step:  0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <module>
     12 print('Training for step: ', step)
     14 start_time = time.time()
---> 15 dnn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=STEP_SIZE)
     16 elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
     18 print('Seconds Elapsed:', elapsed_time)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py:360, in Estimator.train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    357 hooks.extend(self._convert_train_steps_to_hooks(steps, max_steps))
    359 saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 360 loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    361 logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    362 return self

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py:1186, in Estimator._train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1184   return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1185 else:
-> 1186   return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py:1217, in Estimator._train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1214 estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN,
   1215                                      self.config)
   1216 global_step_tensor = tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step(g)
-> 1217 return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
   1218                                        hooks, global_step_tensor,
   1219                                        saving_listeners)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py:1535, in Estimator._train_with_estimator_spec(self, estimator_spec, worker_hooks, hooks, global_step_tensor, saving_listeners)
   1533       _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
   1534   if current_step == 0:
-> 1535     tf.compat.v1.logging.warn('Training with estimator made no steps. '
   1536                               'Perhaps input is empty or misspecified.')
   1537 return loss

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py:893, in _MonitoredSession.__exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback)
    891 if exception_type in [errors.OutOfRangeError, StopIteration]:
    892   exception_type = None
--> 893 self._close_internal(exception_type)
    894 # __exit__ should return True to suppress an exception.
    895 return exception_type is None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py:931, in _MonitoredSession._close_internal(self, exception_type)
    929   if self._sess is None:
    930     raise RuntimeError('Session is already closed.')
--> 931   self._sess.close()
    932 finally:
    933   self._sess = None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py:1222, in _WrappedSession.close(self)
   1220 if self._sess:
   1221   try:
-> 1222     self._sess.close()
   1223   except _PREEMPTION_ERRORS as e:
   1224     logging.error(
   1225         'An error occurred when attempting to close the '
   1226         'session. This may be due to a preemption in a '
   1227         'connected worker or parameter server. Error: %s', e)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py:1388, in _CoordinatedSession.close(self)
   1386 self._coord.request_stop()
   1387 try:
-> 1388   self._coord.join(
   1389       stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_period_secs,
   1390       ignore_live_threads=True)
   1391 finally:
   1392   try:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py:385, in Coordinator.join(self, threads, stop_grace_period_secs, ignore_live_threads)
    383 self._registered_threads = set()
    384 if self._exc_info_to_raise:
--> 385   six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
    386 elif stragglers:
    387   if ignore_live_threads:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py:718, in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    716         value = tp()
    717     if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 718         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    719     raise value
    720 finally:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_queue_runner.py:95, in _FeedingQueueRunner._run(self, sess, enqueue_op, feed_fn, coord)
     93   break
     94 try:
---> 95   feed_dict = None if feed_fn is None else feed_fn()
     96   sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
     97 except (tf.errors.OutOfRangeError, tf.errors.CancelledError):
     98   # This exception indicates that a queue was closed.

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_functions.py:225, in _OrderedDictNumpyFeedFn.__call__(self)
    223 self._trav = (integer_indexes[-1] + 1) % self._max
    224 feed_dict = {self._index_placeholder: integer_indexes}
--> 225 cols = [
    226     column[integer_indexes]
    227     for column in self._ordered_dict_of_arrays.values()
    228 ]
    229 feed_dict.update(dict(zip(self._col_placeholders, cols)))
    230 return feed_dict

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\inputs\queues\feeding_functions.py:226, in <listcomp>(.0)
    223 self._trav = (integer_indexes[-1] + 1) % self._max
    224 feed_dict = {self._index_placeholder: integer_indexes}
    225 cols = [
--> 226     column[integer_indexes]
    227     for column in self._ordered_dict_of_arrays.values()
    228 ]
    229 feed_dict.update(dict(zip(self._col_placeholders, cols)))
    230 return feed_dict

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:985, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    982     key = np.asarray(key, dtype=bool)
    983     return self._get_values(key)
--> 985 return self._get_with(key)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1020, in Series._get_with(self, key)
   1016 if key_type == "integer":
   1017     # We need to decide whether to treat this as a positional indexer
   1018     #  (i.e. self.iloc) or label-based (i.e. self.loc)
   1019     if not self.index._should_fallback_to_positional:
-> 1020         return self.loc[key]
   1021     else:
   1022         return self.iloc[key]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:967, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
    964 axis = self.axis or 0
    966 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 967 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1191, in _LocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1188     if hasattr(key, "ndim") and key.ndim > 1:
   1189         raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
-> 1191     return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
   1193 # nested tuple slicing
   1194 if is_nested_tuple(key, labels):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1132, in _LocIndexer._getitem_iterable(self, key, axis)
   1129 self._validate_key(key, axis)
   1131 # A collection of keys
-> 1132 keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)
   1133 return self.obj._reindex_with_indexers(
   1134     {axis: [keyarr, indexer]}, copy=True, allow_dups=True
   1135 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1327, in _LocIndexer._get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1324 ax = self.obj._get_axis(axis)
   1325 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1327 keyarr, indexer = ax._get_indexer_strict(key, axis_name)
   1329 return keyarr, indexer

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5782, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   5779 else:
   5780     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 5782 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   5784 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
   5785 if isinstance(key, Index):
   5786     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5845, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5844 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
-> 5845 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: '[12993, 13001, 13006, 13007, 13009, 13011, 13021, 13025, 13028, 13031, 13035, 13036, 13041, 13047, 13048, 13049, 13050, 13057, 13059, 13069, 13070, 13074, 13075, 13078, 13079, 13084, 13090, 13091, 13093, 13098, 13099, 13105, 13108, 13126, 13128, 13132, 13133, 13134, 13138, 13151, 13152, 13157, 13163, 13164, 13168, 13169, 13174, 13181, 13184, 13188, 13189, 13190, 13193, 13194, 13195, 13196, 13198, 13199, 13205, 13206, 13208, 13213, 13214, 13218, 13226, 13228, 13229, 13233, 13236, 13238, 13239, 13241, 13243, 13245] not in index'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the input data. Try appending `.values` to your pandas.Series objects in order to convert them to lists like this:

```
# Training input
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': train.description.values}, 
    train.sentiment.values,
    batch_size=256, 
    num_epochs=None, 
    shuffle=True)

# Prediction for training set
predict_train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': train.description.values}, 
    train.sentiment.values, 
    shuffle=False)

# Prediction for validation set
predict_val_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': validate.description.values}, 
    validate.sentiment.values, 
    shuffle=False)

# Prediction for test set
predict_test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'review': test.description.values}, 
    test.sentiment.values, 
    shuffle=False)
```

That should work.